# How to position a popover in css

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#products-list:popover-open {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  inset: unset;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="container">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="parent">
        <button class="trigger-btn" type="button" popovertarget="products-list">Products</button>
        <div id="products-list" popover>
          <ul>
            <li>Prod1</li>
            <li>Prod1</li>
            <li>Prod1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm learning the new Popover api

I want to build a dropdown nav using the new popover api, so I wrote the above demo, current behavior is the popover is in the left of the page, I want to put it under the products button

[image]

I tried to override `:popover-open` css, but don't know why the `position: absolute` doesn't work, it should be in the parent box.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Links to other sites aren't adequate.

Comment: If you don't take the time to post your "*[mcve]*" code it's unlikely that you'll get any particularly good answers.

Comment: I just edited his question and made a snippet though as mentioned he could take time to make a snippet when asking a question. So maybe we can reconsider reopening it

Comment: For frontend problems, I think a codepen link is much easier to understand what problem I want to solve.

Comment: @Joey a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285) is like a Codepen only better, because you don’t have to leave Stack Overflow. I have voted to reopen the question. However, even now that we have the runnable example, it’s still not clear to me what is wrong with the behaviour. You need to edit your question to clearly describe the difference between your desired result and your actual result.

Comment: @BrettDonald I edited the question, please take a look again

Comment: I'm on a Mac. When using Safari, the popover IS under the products button, just where you want it. In Chrome it is positioned on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anchor positioning](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/introducing-popover-api#anchor_positioning) is coming, but the only major browser with support for it is Chrome, and as it is considered an experimental feature, you have to use a [flag](https://caniuse.com/?search=anchor%20positioning) to switch it on.

Until anchor positioning is widely available, popovers created with the Popover API can only be positioned relative to the viewport (by default they are in the centre).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add right: 0;

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#products-list:popover-open {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  inset: unset;
  margin: 0;
  right:0;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="container">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="parent">
        <button class="trigger-btn" type="button" popovertarget="products-list">Products</button>
        <div id="products-list" popover>
          <ul>
            <li>Prod1</li>
            <li>Prod1</li>
            <li>Prod1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I want the dropdown list align with the products button. In my demo, the products button is at the right so adding `right: 0` would work. But I want a more general solution that can automatically aligh the dropdown with the button.